# Optimize Cassandra query performance

Tags: database, performance, cassandra, query-optimization, database-schema

I am using Cassandra to store 100M entries of data, and am trying to optimize the read and write queries. Currently, the schema looks like this:

```
DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS reviews_db;

CREATE KEYSPACE reviews_db WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};

USE reviews_db;

CREATE TABLE reviews(
id INT,
houseId INT, 
name TEXT,
picture TEXT,
reviewText TEXT,
reviewDate TEXT,
accuracyRating INT,
locationRating INT,
communicationRating INT,
checkinRating INT,
cleanlinessRating INT,
valueRating INT,
overallRating DECIMAL,
PRIMARY KEY(id, houseId)
);

CREATE INDEX ON reviews (houseId);

COPY reviews (id, houseId, name, picture, reviewText, reviewDate, accuracyRating, locationRating, communicationRating, checkinRating, cleanlinessRating, valueRating, overallRating) FROM './database/data/reviews1.csv' WITH DELIMITER=',' AND HEADER=FALSE;
```

When I run the query `select id,houseid from reviews where houseid = 9999954;`

the trace looks like this:

```
Tracing session: 36fc1b20-a011-11e8-ac04-9109b2e8334a

activity                                                                                                                               | timestamp                  | source    | source_elapsed | client
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
                                                                                                                Execute CQL3 query | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.218000 | 127.0.0.1 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
                                     Parsing select id,houseid from reviews where houseid = 9999954; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.219000 | 127.0.0.1 |            253 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                 Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.219000 | 127.0.0.1 |            448 | 127.0.0.1
              Index mean cardinalities are reviews_houseid_idx:1. Scanning with reviews_houseid_idx. [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.219000 | 127.0.0.1 |            968 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Computing ranges to query [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.219000 | 127.0.0.1 |           1073 | 127.0.0.1       
Submitting range requests on 257 ranges with a concurrency of 257 (0.003515625 rows per range expected) [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.220000 | 127.0.0.1 |           1668 | 127.0.0.1                                       
                                                               Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.221000 | 127.0.0.1 |           2260 | 127.0.0.1
                                                Executing read on reviews_db.reviews using index reviews_houseid_idx [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.221000 | 127.0.0.1 |           2341 | 127.0.0.1
                                                     Executing single-partition query on reviews.reviews_houseid_idx [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.221000 | 127.0.0.1 |           2400 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.221000 | 127.0.0.1 |           2445 | 127.0.0.1
                                           Skipped 0/5 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.221000 | 127.0.0.1 |           2546 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1029 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.227000 | 127.0.0.1 |           8775 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                            Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 819 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.228000 | 127.0.0.1 |           9481 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1176 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.229000 | 127.0.0.1 |          10102 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 517 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.234000 | 127.0.0.1 |          15699 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1259 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.241000 | 127.0.0.1 |          22535 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.241000 | 127.0.0.1 |          22724 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.241000 | 127.0.0.1 |          22751 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.241000 | 127.0.0.1 |          22779 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.251000 | 127.0.0.1 |          32604 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.258000 | 127.0.0.1 |          39903 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.258000 | 127.0.0.1 |          39959 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.258000 | 127.0.0.1 |          39987 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.260000 | 127.0.0.1 |          41753 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.269000 | 127.0.0.1 |          50605 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1214 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.275000 | 127.0.0.1 |          57061 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.276000 | 127.0.0.1 |          57325 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.276000 | 127.0.0.1 |          57412 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.276000 | 127.0.0.1 |          57462 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.278000 | 127.0.0.1 |          59387 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.287000 | 127.0.0.1 |          68588 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1214 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.294000 | 127.0.0.1 |          75900 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.295000 | 127.0.0.1 |          76188 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.295000 | 127.0.0.1 |          76267 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.295000 | 127.0.0.1 |          76321 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.302000 | 127.0.0.1 |          83846 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.313000 | 127.0.0.1 |          94648 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1214 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.322000 | 127.0.0.1 |         103400 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.322000 | 127.0.0.1 |         103745 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.322000 | 127.0.0.1 |         103833 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.322001 | 127.0.0.1 |         103901 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.336000 | 127.0.0.1 |         117832 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.344000 | 127.0.0.1 |         125175 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.344000 | 127.0.0.1 |         125275 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.344000 | 127.0.0.1 |         125346 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.347000 | 127.0.0.1 |         128201 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.358000 | 127.0.0.1 |         139767 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1214 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.367000 | 127.0.0.1 |         148635 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.368000 | 127.0.0.1 |         149174 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.368000 | 127.0.0.1 |         149290 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.368000 | 127.0.0.1 |         149357 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.371000 | 127.0.0.1 |         152815 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.379000 | 127.0.0.1 |         160651 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1214 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.388000 | 127.0.0.1 |         169148 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.388000 | 127.0.0.1 |         169607 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.388000 | 127.0.0.1 |         169690 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.388000 | 127.0.0.1 |         169759 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.389000 | 127.0.0.1 |         170955 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.399000 | 127.0.0.1 |         180652 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                         Executing single-partition query on reviews [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.406000 | 127.0.0.1 |         188039 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.407000 | 127.0.0.1 |         188130 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.407000 | 127.0.0.1 |         188180 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1215 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.412000 | 127.0.0.1 |         193070 | 127.0.0.1
                                                               Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1009 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.420000 | 127.0.0.1 |         201613 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1214 [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.427000 | 127.0.0.1 |         208842 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                              Read 9 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.427000 | 127.0.0.1 |         209064 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                           Merged data from memtables and 3 sstables [ReadStage-2] | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.428000 | 127.0.0.1 |         209165 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                  Request complete | 2018-08-14 15:27:23.427622 | 127.0.0.1 |         209622 | 127.0.0.1
```

The query takes 209ms, and I want to cut it down to less than 50ms. Are there ways that I could achieve such time?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Create a query table designed around `houseid`:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews_by_house_id(
  id INT,
  houseId INT, 
  name TEXT,
  picture TEXT,
  reviewText TEXT,
  reviewDate TEXT,
  accuracyRating INT,
  locationRating INT,
  communicationRating INT,
  checkinRating INT,
  cleanlinessRating INT,
  valueRating INT,
  overallRating DECIMAL,
  PRIMARY KEY(houseId,id));
```

Secondary index queries (even on a single node instance) will never achieve that level of performance.  If you really need the original table, then keep them both in sync with BATCHed writes.  I'd be willing to bet that a query by `houseId` on this table would fit your performance requirements.

Comment: I tried the above method and was able to bring down the latency to around 75-80ms, which is much better than the previous time of 209ms. However, as I try to meet the goal of 50ms or less, are there other ways you might consider? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform effective query on the non-partition key, like your `houseId` because it will require scanning of all existing partitions & extracting data from them to match your field. You can have condition on the `houseId` if you have condition on `id` as well.

In Cassandra you create a data model around queries that you need to execute, so you have following possibilities:

- Create the secondary table with `houseId` as a partition key, and fill it yourself (maybe with less data);
- Use materialized views (although they are still considered experimental feature);
- Use secondary indexes, but this should be checked as they could be used only in specific cases. You can [read more about them in this blog post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-native-secondary-index-deep-dive).

If you're have a chance to use DataStax enterprise, you have another possibility - DSE Search. Just create a search index on your table, and query will be fulfilled by Solr that is underneath of DSE Search (although latencies will be higher than in case of "plain Cassandra").